# OnClick not working properly within recycler adaptor in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, interface, onclicklistener

Hello stackoverflow community,
i am working on recycler adaptor within fragment, on which i have created an interface on click listener for which i have a callback in fragment. the problem i am facing is its working some times but most of the time its not generating the callback. let me know what i am doing wrong in this..

is it that my View is not getting the click listener, as i have added ripple effect which is not shown on view?

or i need to put the listener in the activity instead of fragment, which i did but no result.

the code to my adatper class

```
class UserMoneyRequestsAdaptor(
postItems: ArrayList<UserMoneyRequest>?, recItemClick: RecItemClick
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder>() {

private var isLoaderVisible = false
var mPostItems: ArrayList<UserMoneyRequest>? = postItems
var recItemClick: RecItemClick? = null

init {
    this.recItemClick = recItemClick
}

interface RecItemClick {
    fun onAcceptReqest(position: Int, moneyRequestModel: UserMoneyRequest)
    fun onCancelReqest(position: Int, moneyRequestModel: UserMoneyRequest)
}

companion object {
    private const val VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 0
    private const val VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL = 1
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL -> ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.user_request_list_item, parent, false)
        )
        VIEW_TYPE_LOADING -> ProgressHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false)
        )
        else -> ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.user_request_list_item, parent, false)
        )
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.onBind(position)
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if (isLoaderVisible) {
        if (position == mPostItems!!.size - 1) VIEW_TYPE_LOADING else VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL
    } else {
        VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return if (mPostItems == null) 0 else mPostItems!!.size
}

fun addItems(postItems: ArrayList<UserMoneyRequest>) {
    mPostItems!!.addAll(postItems!!)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun addLoading() {
    isLoaderVisible = true

    mPostItems!!.add(
        UserMoneyRequest(
            "-1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", UserAccount(
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                Currency("", "", ""),
                User("", "")
            )
        )
    )
    notifyItemInserted(mPostItems!!.size - 1)
}

fun addData(listItems: ArrayList<UserMoneyRequest>) {
    val size = mPostItems!!.size
    mPostItems!!.addAll(listItems)
    val sizeNew = this.mPostItems!!.size
    notifyItemRangeChanged(size, sizeNew)
}

fun addAll(list: java.util.ArrayList<UserMoneyRequest>) {
    mPostItems!!.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun updateItem(pos: Int, paymentLinkListModel: UserMoneyRequest) {
    notifyItemChanged(pos)
}

fun addOneItem(postItem: UserMoneyRequest) {
    mPostItems!!.add(0, postItem)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun removeOneItem(position: Int) {
    mPostItems!!.removeAt(position)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun getlist(positionIndex: Int): UserMoneyRequest {
    return mPostItems!![positionIndex]
}

fun removeLoading() {
    isLoaderVisible = false
    val position = mPostItems!!.size - 1
    val item: UserMoneyRequest = getItem(position)
    if (item.id == "-1") {
        mPostItems!!.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }
}

fun clear() {
    mPostItems!!.clear()
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun getItem(position: Int): UserMoneyRequest {
    return mPostItems!![position]
}

inner class ViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View?) :
    BaseViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val tvStatus = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.requestStatus) as TextView
    val tvAmount = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.requestAmount) as TextView

    private val tvDate = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.requestDateAndTime) as TextView
    private val requestedFrom = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.requestedFromId) as TextView
    private val requestAccept = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.requestAcceptStatus) as TextView
    private val requestDecline = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.requestDecline) as TextView
    private val requestNotes = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.requestNotes) as TextView

    val context: Context = itemView!!.context

    override fun clear() {}

    override fun onBind(position: Int) {
        super.onBind(position)
        val moneyRequest = mPostItems!![position]
        tvAmount.text = (moneyRequest.amount.toDouble() / 100).toString() + moneyRequest.user_account.currency.code
        tvDate.text = getMonthDateTime(moneyRequest.created_at)

        requestedFrom.text = moneyRequest.user_account.user!!.email
        requestNotes.text = "Notes: " + moneyRequest.notes

        setStatus(context, moneyRequest)

        //first on clicklistener
        requestAccept.setOnClickListener {
            recItemClick!!.onAcceptReqest(position, moneyRequest)
        }

        //second on clicklistener
        requestDecline.setOnClickListener {
            recItemClick!!.onCancelReqest(position, moneyRequest)
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun setStatus(context: Context, moneyRequest: UserMoneyRequest) {
        when (moneyRequest.status) {
            "0" -> {
                tvStatus.text = moneyRequest.statusStr
                tvStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.request_pending_text_bg)
                requestAccept.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                requestAccept.isClickable = true
                requestDecline.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                requestDecline.isClickable = true
            }
            "1" -> {
                tvStatus.text = moneyRequest.statusStr
                tvStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.request_active_background_text)
            }
            "2" -> {
                tvStatus.text = moneyRequest.statusStr
                tvStatus.setTextColor(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        context,
                        R.color.color_status_rejected
                    )
                )
                tvStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.request_canceled_text_background)
            }
            "3" -> {
                tvStatus.text = moneyRequest.statusStr
                tvStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.request_rejected_text_background)
            }
            "4" -> {
                tvStatus.text = moneyRequest.statusStr
                tvStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.request_completed_text_background)
            }
        }
    }
}

inner class ProgressHolder internal constructor(itemView: View?) :
    BaseViewHolder(itemView) {
    override fun clear() {}
}
```

}

my root element of the recycler view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relPayoutRequestItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailsLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/amountLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/requestedFromId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/spartanmbbold"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/dummy_text_transfers"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/requestNotes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/spartanmb_semibold"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:text="Notes: NIL"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/amountLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_68sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/requestAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/spartan_mb_medium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:text="@string/dummy_transaction_amount"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/detailsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/requestDateAndTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/spartan_mb_medium"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="@string/dummy_transfer_time"
            android:textColor="@color/transaction_time_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/requestStatus"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/acceptRipple"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/spartanmbbold"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:text="@string/dummy_payment_method"/>

        <!-- first view for clicklistener-->
        <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
            android:id="@+id/acceptRipple"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
            app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/requestRippleDecline"
            app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/ripple_black"
            app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
            app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
            app:mrl_rippleRoundedCorners="@dimen/_12sdp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/requestAcceptStatus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/spartanmbbold"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:lines="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@drawable/user_request_active_background_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:text="@string/accept"/>

        </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

       <!-- second view for clicklistener-->
        <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
            android:id="@+id/requestRippleDecline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
            app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/ripple_black"
            app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
            app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
            app:mrl_rippleRoundedCorners="@dimen/_12sdp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/requestDecline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/spartanmbbold"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:lines="1"
                android:background="@drawable/user_request_rejected_text_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:text="@string/decline"/>

        </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottomlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:background="@color/settings_screen_seperator" />
</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Not the answer, but you should set listeners when creating a ViewHolder, not when binding it with data.

Comment: https://developer.android.google.cn/courses/android-basics-kotlin/unit-3 go thrue this course, and you will clarify many thing for your self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was within the view, i was using nested scroll view which was not generating the click listener

Answer (score 4):

Please check the below code, it is written on kotlin if you want it in java please let me know I will share.

```
class LocationAdapter (
private val list: List<Any>,
private val listener: ClickItemListener
) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

interface ClickItemListener {
    fun onClicked(model: Any,position:Int)
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(ItemLocationBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, parentPosition: Int) {

    Timber.d("onBindViewHolder" + parentPosition)
    val model = list.get(parentPosition)

    holder.bind.name.text = model.name

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onClicked(model,parentPosition)
    }
}

inner class ViewHolder(private var binding: ItemLocationBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    val bind = binding
}

}

//call in Activity or Fragment
locationList.adapter = LocationAdapter(sharedViewModel.listOfPlace,
        object : LocationAdapter.ClickItemListener {
            override fun onClicked(model: Any, position: Int) {
                Timber.d("$position")
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
class YourAdapter(private val onItemClick: (String) -> Unit) {
...
}
```

Then in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(
            ...,
            onItemClick,
            ...,
        )
    }
```

Then in your view holder bind method

```
fun bind(onItemClick: (String) -> Unit) {
   onItemClick("Whatever")
}
```

Then where you create your adapter have this :

```
 val yourAdapter =
            YourAdapter { test ->
                //Here you'd get "Whatever" as string since is what you have in your ViewHolder
            }
```

In case you need to notify the Activity then you have to have a callback between your Fragment and Activity, or just do the casting (not recommended) and call the method you want.

Example of doing this (there are more ways)
https://gist.github.com/zacharymikel/40aa61b2ff4d0b1ae267212d7dd965e5
https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/android/activity-and-fragments-communication/

Comment: the problem is its working perfectly in activities, and even some time in fragment but not effectively..

Comment: Where are you creating the adapter? Put it inside your `onViewCreated()` after the `super.onViewCreated()`, it should work. (in fragment)

Comment: i have checked it, may  be i really need to change my adaptor than.. but i have added lot of things like pagination and logics. and the on click button is not always visible on the list. so may be i am not managing the state of my recycler view ?

Comment: i tried your solution and it didn't helped